# How to set cookie in curl post request in c

Tags: c, post, curl, cookies

I have set the cookie into HTTP header in this way.

```
     .....
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "charsets: utf-8");

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost:9763/addApp.jag");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,reqbody);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, body_callback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, header_callback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA,&cookiec);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE,cookie);
    res=curl_easy_perform(curl);
    ......
```

In server side when I retrieved post data they seem to be null. But when I check from Wireshark actually those post data are sent. But when I remove

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE,cookie);
```

I can access the post data in the server side. If I make any mistake in my post request please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it little bit complicated to find answer for this. Because when I set the cookie it should be excluded \r\n characters in cookie value which is coming from server side. If somebody want to do this here is the sample code

```
   struct response_data *makeCURLRequest(char* reqbody,char* cookie,int  memorySize,char* url){
                    CURL *curl;
                    struct url_data data;
                    data.size = 0;
                    data.data = malloc(memorySize);
                    if(NULL == data.data) {

                                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory.\n");
                                return NULL;
                    }
                    struct site_cookie cookiec;
                    cookiec.size=0;
                    cookiec.cookie=malloc(256);
                    if(NULL == cookiec.cookie) {
                                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory.\n");
                                return NULL;
                    }
                    struct response_data* res_data;
                    res_data=malloc(sizeof(struct response_data));
                    res_data->res_body=malloc(1000);
                    res_data->res_cookie=malloc(256);
                    if(NULL == res_data->res_body || NULL==res_data->res_cookie) {
                                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory.\n");
                                return NULL;
                    }
                     struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
                     headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: Subscription/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                     headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: Subscription/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                     headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "charsets: utf-8");
                    data.data[0] = '\0';
                    cookiec.cookie[0]= '\0';
                    res_data->res_body[0]='\0';
                    res_data->res_cookie[0]='\0';
                    buf_t *buf = buf_size(NULL, BUFFER_SIZE);
                    CURLcode res;
                    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
                    curl = curl_easy_init();
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,url);
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,reqbody);
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, fetch_data);
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, buf);
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, header_callback);
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA,&cookiec);
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE,cookie);
                    res=curl_easy_perform(curl);
                    if(res != CURLE_OK){
                        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",curl_easy_strerror(res));
                        return NULL;
                    }
                     curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
                     char *jsonstr = buf_tostr(buf);
                     free(buf->data);
                     free(buf);
                     strcpy(res_data->res_body,jsonstr);
                     strcpy(res_data->res_cookie,cookiec.cookie);
            return res_data;
  }
```

full source code can be found here https://github.com/GPrathap/REST_API_in_C/blob/master/libs/curlreq.c